# Debugger is jumping around, not sure what I did

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, visual-studio-debugging

I am using visual studio 2013 Ultimate and am having the problem when I step through code that the debugger is jumping around.  I was able to find 2 articles here on stack overflow but neither of them solved my problem.

```
auto it = m_actorComponents.begin();
while (it != m_actorComponents.end())
{
    delete it->second;
    it->second = nullptr;
    it = m_actorComponents.erase(it);
}
```

In the piece of code above, for example, when I try to step through it enters the loop then executes the delete line, then jumps to the erase line, then jumps up to the nullptr line.  It repeats this pattern for every iteration.  Some different parts of code seem to just jump around sporadically.  Before this happened I was playing around with Profile Guided Optimization so I believe it has something to do with that, but cannot figure out how to fix it.  I have cleaned and rebuilt solution, deleted debug and release folders, etc.  Does anyone know how I can turn this off because it makes it very difficult to figure out what is going on.

On a side note, I am using _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF); to check for memory leaks.  There are none upon program exit, yet everytime I reload a game level during runtime the framerate drops.  If I continue to reload I can even get it down to 4 FPS and it will sit there.  To me, this means there is a memory leak present upon level load that is somehow cleaned up on program exit.  Anyone have any ideas on how to track this or any good profiling tools for C++ memory usage during runtime?

Comment: Make sure you turned off optimizations in the C++ project settings.  If not, turn them off and rebuild your application.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot sometimes...I checked under "Command Line" and didn't see any /O switches so I figured I already deleted it and turned it off.  Upon searching for the /O under the "All Options" section though, I found it.  Sheesh.  Can't believe I spent a day trying to figure that out.  Thanks